# Mono & WInforms on OS X

Tags: c#, winforms, macos, mono, monodevelop

I have just begun to explore the mono winforms environment and I cannot work out how to start a program from within monodevelop without a console session being started.

My simple program runs okay but when it exits a terminal session is always created & waiting for me to 'press any key'. I guess I could arrange things so that the terminal window closes automatically, but I would rather the app just ran 'natively', is this possible or does the way mono & .net function work preclude it?

As shown in the [examples at Zetcode](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/monowinformstutorial/firststeps/), in 'Main' the rest of the code is started with 'application.run(new aFunction());', I thought this might be the cause of the terminal session occurring but replacing it with: 

`myNewClass n = new myNewClass();
n.aFunction();`

causes the program to not run at all (or maybe just exit without doing anything).

I am an experienced programmer but not familiar at all with C# or the mono/.net environment so 'stating the obvious' may be all that is required in an answer.

Comment: Your question is not clear. The reason your terminal session is not closing could be a system setting. The code you posted does not make any sense. Unless the class you are starting inherits from a Form then Application.Run(myNewClass) won't work. What type of application are you planning on making this?  I am actually shocked that Mono even as Application.Run since its suppose to be limited to Windows applications based on the documentation.

Comment: I took a quick look at the page, there is NOTHING to indicate this code would work on any other operating system other then Windows with Mono installed.  You cannot use a Windows Form on any other operating system other then Windows.

Comment: @RamHound Well, the code does work on operating systems other than Windows otherwise I would not have a problem. Maybe I have misunderstood something but why else would mono exist other than to provide a portable platform for .net programs?

Comment: @Ramhound MWF works very well on OSX. I think you misunderstand there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) will usually let you start a program with or without it running in an external console.

In [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) 2.8 on Linux you can control this by context clicking on a project in the solution tree and selecting **Options**; then **Run on external console** under the **Run** section. I'm not sure if you can disable this on OSX.

Comment: Found the 'run' options under the Project/program Options menu. Does exactlt what it says on the tin so thank you for pointing me in the right direction.